# How to get all the characters within the range specified by the matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, character

Is it possible to get all the characters within the range specified by the matrix

**For Example:**

My matrix is something like this:

```
A = ['a' 'b' 'c';      %// Start index
     'd' 'e' 'f'];     %// End Index
```

**Expected output vector** (cell-Array of string)

```
Out = {'abcd'    'bcde'    'cdef'}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want them as string like `{'a:b','b:e','c:f'}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
out = arrayfun(@colon,A(1,:),A(2,:),'uni',0);
```

**How does it work?**

> Elements in each row are passed one by one (at the same time) using `arrayfun` and all the characters between them including the boundary characters are returned.

**Input:**

```
A = ['a' 'b' 'c';
     'd' 'e' 'f'];
```

> "Output is a vector cell-array"

**Output:**

```
>> out

out = 

'abcd'    'bcde'    'cdef'
```

---

If you want them in this format `{'a:b','b:e','c:f'}` you could use this:

```
out = arrayfun(@(x,y) strcat(x,':',y),A(1,:),A(2,:),'uni',0);

>> out

out = 

'a:d'    'b:e'    'c:f'
```

Comment: From 2xm matrix M, I want to get m intervals [M(1,1):M(2,1)  M(1,2):M(2,2) ...M(1,m):M(2,m)]

Comment: Perhaps an example with numbers (instead of chars) would be clearer?

Comment: @YongWookShin Isn't that what i got?